# Grouping notifications from multiple apps

Tags: android

Is it possible to group notifications from foreground services together, from multiple apps?

I will have various apps that I don't want to take up all the users notification tray space if they're running at the same time.

Comment: I do not believe that is possible, sorry. If they are that closely coupled, perhaps they should be just one app, rather than a suite of apps.

Comment: I thought that might be the case :( thanks. It's not possible right now, but it's an option to consider in the future of consolidating them.